# Datatables - Search Box filter on specific column

Tags: jquery, datatables

i am using Datatables and i want to make the search box "filtration" applied on a specific columns like "name" and "email" , is it possible and how ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `columnsDef` OR `columns` options.
The  code disabled search for the specified columns base on **Column Index**.

```
'columnDefs' : [     // see https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.searchable
    { 
       'searchable'    : false, 
       'targets'       : [0,1,4] 
    },
]

"columns": [
    { "searchable": false },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
]
```

Go thro this link https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.searchable

Comment: thank , i used this :
 columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
                {data: 'Edit', name: 'Edit' ,searchable: false},
                {data: 'Delete', name: 'Delete',searchable: false}
            ],

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `columns().search()` instead of `filter()`.

[Click here for more details on datatables.net, including examples](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search())